# How to enable Windows features "MSMQ Server" and "MSMQ Server Core" using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to enable Windows features "MSMQ Server" and "MSMQ Server Core" using PowerShell with the below command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'MSMQ-Server' -All -NoRestart
```

But the above command enables only the "MSMQ Server" and not "MSMQ Server Core". I want a PowerShell command which enables both "MSMQ Server" and "MSMQ Server Core" feature. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mani Athreya S

Comment: I don't see a feature called 'MSMS Server Core'.  Are you sure that's the name?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable all MSMQ features, you can run this command.  For the record, I do not see a MSMS-Server-Core feature available in my up-to-date Server 2019 VM.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName MSMQ* -Online |
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -NoRestart -Verbose
```

Comment: It did work when I run the above PS command manually but deploying via SCCM, it throws an error "One or several parent features are disabled so current feature cannot be enabled". I even added disabling the MSMQ feature before enabling them in the script bu that dint work either.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's moving the goal post for the question.  Mark as completed and then ask in a Configuration Manager specific forum to get help / guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add an `-All` flag to `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature`. This installs the prerequisites of the specified feature.